# Binding treeview to a property of different collections

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm currently converting a WPF app to a WinForms app, and I'm having some trouble when it comes to a treeview.

I have four nodes which are set up in the designer like so:

```
this.treeView1.Name = "treeView1";
treeNode1.Name = "shapeNode";
treeNode1.Text = "Shape Files";
treeNode2.Name = "mdbNode";
treeNode2.Text = "MDB Files";
treeNode3.Name = "tiffNode";
treeNode3.Text = "Tiff Files";
treeNode4.Name = "kmlNode";
treeNode4.Text = "KML Files";
this.treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[] {
treeNode1,
treeNode2,
treeNode3,
treeNode4});
```

I also have four observable collections that are supposed to correspond with each treeNode, specifically the "Name" property each of these types of objects has:

```
public ObservableCollection<ShapeFileFeatureLayer> ShapeFileLayers
{
    get { return mapModel.ShapeFileLayers; }
    set { mapModel.ShapeFileLayers = value; OnPropertyChanged("ShapeFileLayers"); }
}

public ObservableCollection<PersonalGeoDatabaseFeatureLayer> MdbFileLayers
{
    get { return mapModel.MdbFileLayers; }
    set { mapModel.MdbFileLayers = value; OnPropertyChanged("MdbFileLayers"); }
}

public ObservableCollection<GeoTiffRasterLayer> TiffFileLayers
{
    get { return mapModel.TiffFileLayers; }
    set { mapModel.TiffFileLayers = value; OnPropertyChanged("TiffFileLayers"); }
}

public ObservableCollection<KmlFeatureLayer> KmlFileLayers
{
    get { return mapModel.KmlFileLayers; }
    set { mapModel.KmlFileLayers = value; OnPropertyChanged("KmlFileLayers"); }
}
```

So for each item in one of the collections, it'll populate under the correct node.

Now in WPF, following MVVM, I just add a new TreeViewItem, and bind it's ItemsSource to the correct collection in the viewmodel, and bind the context/text of the child node to "Name" . But I can't do this in winforms. In fact, I don't see a "child" or "items" property for the parent nodes, or any bindable property at all.

Do I really have to add/remove nodes manually to the parent nodes every time the collections change?

Comment: To clarify - you're going from WinForms to WPF or vice-versa?

Comment: WPF to winforms. It's dumb I know, it's a requirement right now though.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is tough or almost impossible to handle.

But I have another recommendation.

Winforms has capability of *WPF interoperability*.

You have to use `ElementHost` control. You can find this control in toolbox under *WPF Interoperability*.

Just add `ElementHost` control to your winform. And then add the WPF control to `ElementHost`.

If you have multiple WPF controls, create WPF user control with all those controls and add the user control to `ElementHost`.

This makes your job simple with very less code changes.

For a sample look into below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: I was thinking about going this route, I'm just not 100% sure If I can. I originally wrapped the entire project in WinForms to satisfy the users/people this is for, and they didn't want it. Something about WPF not running on linux using mono (would it still work with elementhost? I don't know).